# Member types в с++

Tags: c++

Нигде не могу найти пояснение по вопросу "Что такое member types(типы-члены) в с++?", в документации тоже про них ничего не нашел.
Возможно, тут подскажете...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/10cwk72y.aspx

Comment: Больше похоже про это спрашивали https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_C%2B%2B#%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: К сожалению, тут я уже читал и не увидел то, что мне нужно. Меня интересуют именно типы-члены.
Возможно, я что-то не до конца понимаю, но для прояснения ясности вопроса приведу ссылку на контейнер List, в котором описаны его типы-члены, но не написано что такое ТИП-ЧЛЕН. Меня интересует именно формулировка.
http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: Типы которые являются членом класса. Какая другая формулировка тут нужна?

Comment: Преподавателю такая формулировка не понравилась )))

Comment: Тогда спросите преподователя, какая формулировка ему нравится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример:

```
class Foo {
public:
    typedef int my_int;
    using my_double = double;
    Foo() = default;
    ~Foo() = default;
};

int main() {
    Foo::my_int bar = 1;
    Foo::my_double baz = 1.0;

    return 0;
}
```

Здесь `my_int` и `my_double` это и есть *member types*.

**UPDATED**
*member types* (типы-члены) - в стандарте называются *nested type name* (имя вложенного типа), он же *внутренний класс* или *вложенный класс* является классом, объявленным полностью внутри тела другого класса или интерфейса.

Comment: я понимаю их реализацию, но мне нужно именно определение )

Comment: @ЮрийКоротков Извините, ну Вы же  себе противоречите. "(типы-члены) - в стандарте называются nested type name"  "my_int и my_double это и есть member types"